# Update same column with different values based another column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this table

```
Type   Price
A1     900
A2     800
A3     700
A4     600
```

I want to execute a update query where the Prices for A1, A3 and A4 increased by 5%
The price for A2 must be increased with 6,5%

I tried to use `Case` or `IIF` and many more. But i cant figure out how i can put this in one query.

Comment: Why is 'A2' handled differently?  If you're hard-coding , just use a where clause.  `SET Price = price + (price * .05) where `type <> 'A2'`, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following should work. I

```
UPDATE <table>
SET PRICE = IIF([TYPE] IN ("A1","A3", "A4"); [Price]*1,05; [Price]*1,065)
```

Comment: Replace ";" with "," and "," with "." if you are not working with german locales: `UPDATE <table>
SET PRICE = IIF([TYPE] IN ("A1", "A3", "A4"), [Price] * 1.05, [Price] * 1.065)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `switch` expression:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET    price = price * SWITCH (
                          type IN ('A1', 'A3'), 1.05,
                          type = 'A4', 1.065)
WHERE  type IN ('A1', 'A3', 'A4')
```