# How to update the same column with different values?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm looking for a solution to update same column with different value based on keys from ID column.

| ID | Result_Required(ID+alphabets in seq) |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | A1_abc |
| A1 | A1_def |
| A1 | A1_ghi |
| A2 | A2_abc |
| A3 | A3_abc |
| A3 | A3_def |
| : . | : . |
| A(n) | AN_something |

I've looking into this [reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26679126/update-same-column-with-different-values-based-another-column) but it is not feasible undefined number of IDs.

Comment: `update sample_table set target_column = case when <condition1> then <value1> when <condition2> then <value2> else <otherwise value> end` Please clarify an algorithm of update: what are those `abc`, `xyz` ec and how are they calculated.

Comment: @astentx - abc and xyz are just string. These are getting calculated from different SP for example - seq_aplha() we can use the same.

Comment: What is *something* for the 9th, 10th, ... row of A1?

Comment: @forpas-  `A9` it'll again start from `abc` and same for `A10`.

Comment: I saw that you edited your sample data, so check my new question.

Comment: @forpas - Sorry I made a typo so fixed it.
If sequence get exhausted then It'll circle back with `abc_1, def_1... xyz_1` then `abc_2` so on...

Comment: I suspect that you oversimplified your requirement and this makes it hard for anyone who wants to contribute. Post sample data and expected results that reflect your actual data and cover edge cases in your question. Also, a table is in unordered set. So, none of the A1 rows is considered 1st or 2nd... Is there a column which guarantees the order of the rows?

Comment: I would think there's a way to do this with REGEXP and be table driven rather than creating dynamic case statements ... but as the prior comment indicates, the original question leaves too much to interpretation.  Please provide a discrete example showing what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

So, as you said, you have a stored procedure that finds all the strings that you need. So, you can alter your stored procedure by building a string which will look like this:

```
WHEN ID = 'A23' then 'somestring'
```

and you will have a text chunk like the above for each element. You need to concatenate into a variable, I will call it `value` now.

This is how your `UPDATE` is going to be look alike:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET res = <concatenate value here>;
```

Possible problems:

## Large updates

If the proposed approach is too slow or eats up too much memory, then you can break the update down into batches and add ranges to the `where` clause.

## Gaps

Before you do the update, it's advisable to ensure that all records assumed to exist are existing indeed and that unnecessary records are cleaned up, so the assumptions of your `update` will be plausible.

## Building up the WHEN elements

If you have a cursor and loop it, you can use an index, starting from 1 and ending with the last element, n and always build a textual data for your ID. Based on your example, it seems that it is of the form of `A<theindexnumber>`. It is possible that the actual rule in your case is different, so you will need to implement an algorithm that reliably maps your index to a corresponding ID where the text should be updated to.